# The following permissions have not been approved for use... Facebook error

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

In my facebook canvas game i suddenly got this error.

"The following permissions have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: publish_actions.
Submit them for review or learn more."

i was not getting this before.
error screenshot is here.

https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-9/q71/s480x480/10525921_10204168417080416_9152860150486563690_n.jpg

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @EthanLeroy  Not yet, this message only appears for me/developer not for other players. and it will disappear after my app reviewed and publish to app center as i understand.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook have changed the way that things work. To use publish_actions so that you can post to a user's wall you now have to submit your app to Facebook's review team so that they can see why/how you are using this permission.

Go to the status & Review section and follow the instructions on there to allow them to review your app/Game.

Answer (score 0):

In your FB App page you should be able to go to "Status & Review" and turn this ON 
"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"
Then it should be live.